# Сохранения булевых значений в приложении

Tags: swift, spritekit

Здравствуйте!
Столкнулся с небольшой проблемой, но надеюсь, что Вы поможете новичку.
Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку значение "true" менялось на "false",или наоборот, а также сохранять результат.
Пытался сделать самостоятельно, но, к сожалению, не вышло(
В общем я хочу сделать кнопку выключения и включения звука в приложении.
Вот я к примеру создаю переменную

```
var soundOnOff : Bool = true
```

Затем я хочу сделать так, чтобы в каждом из значений были какие-то параметры. Отключение звука, к примеру:

```
buttonSound.volume = 0.0
```

и какие-либо другие параметры.
А так же свои параметры для false.
Как сделать настройки для нажатия кнопки я знаю, так же знаю как сохранять и загружать булевые настройки через NSUserDefaults.
Я просто не понимаю, как сделать так чтобы у каждого булевого значения были свои параметры и чтобы они чередовали друг друга при нажатии на кнопку...

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться с кодом.

Comment: еще раз, вам надо чтоб значение менялось с true на false? о каких параметрах идет речь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то Вам нужен if-else.

Вот ваша переменная `var soundOnOff : Bool = true`

Далее при нажатии кнопки меняете значение на противоположное:

```
soundOnOff = !soundOnOff
```

Далее создаете if-else:

```
if soundOnOff {
// Действия когда значение true, к примеру buttonSound.volume = 1.0
} else {
// Действия когда значение false, а тут buttonSound.volume = 0.0
}
```

Данная запись подходит, если в теле if-else у Вас больше чем одна строка. Если же все что Вам надо, менять значение `buttonSound.volume` с 0 на 1 и наоборот, то используйте тенарный оператор:

```
buttonSound.volume = soundOnOff ? 1 : 0
```

Как это работает - `условие ? действие когда условие верно : действие когда условие лож.` Т.е. если `soundOnOff` true, тогда `buttonSound.volume = 1`, иначе `buttonSound.volume = 0`

Comment: Благодарю, Вас, за ответ! Он мне очень помог)))
soundOnOff = !soundOnOff - вот этой строчки мне как раз и не хватало в коде)))